# .net mvc3 entity deep compare on Where

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-4

My Code for a controller:

```
public ViewResult Index(int? ProjectID)
    {
        var user = HttpContext.User;
        User profile = db.Users.Where(d => d.Email == user.Identity.Name).Single();
        var contracts = db.Contracts.Include(c => c.Project);
        if (!user.IsInRole("Admin"))
        {
            contracts = contracts.Where(p => p.Project.Client == profile.Client );
        }

        if (ProjectID != null)
        {
            contracts = contracts.Where(u => u.ID == ProjectID);
        }

        return View(contracts.ToList());
    }
```

This is suppose to pull up all of the contracts whose parent project has the same client fk as the user currently signed in unless they are an admin. This isn't working.

I am getting the following error when the non-admin's look at the page:

> Unable to create a constant value of type
>   'MembershipExt.Models.Client'. Only primitive types ('such as Int32,
>   String, and Guid') are supported in this context.

Do I need to use a second include or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
contracts = contracts.Where(p => p.Project.Client == profile.Client );
```

i am guessing the problem is in the above line the right hand side of lambda needs to be of simple type that is `int32`, `string` etc but you are having a complex type i.e. `p.Project.Client`

Answer (score 2):

What is the data type for p.Project.Client? I'm guessing that it is a complex type (it has properties off of it). Perhaps what you want is something like this...

```
contracts = contracts.Where(p => p.Project.Client.ClientID == profile.Client.ClientID );
```

Obviously I don't know what the object looks like, but perhaps this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This looks wrong

```
db.Users.Where(d => d.Email == user.Identity.Name)
```

looks like you are comparing email with name

Comment: That is actually right. I have it setup so the username of the account is the person's email. I'm looking in the debug and it is showing up that user.Identity.Name is an email address.

Comment: A lot of sites use an e-mail address as the username, and ASP.NET's built-in membership provider doesn't distinguish (or care) about the format. `Identity.Name` can be any string.

Comment: Ahh.. in my project i just implemented my own login / user mechanism since i didnt need all the roles etc. (and tons of tables in my db)